# setVisible() method not works in static method

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Am a newbie to JFrame, am trying to do a project, in that if a press Logout button the following code is executed perfectly,

```
public void actionlogout() {
    lButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            try {
                new Login();
                setVisible(false);
                dispose();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now my problem is when i trying to call the same actionlogout from another file from same package it asks to change the type of method to static, so i have changed the method to static, but it gives the following error on **setVisible(false)**

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setVisible(boolean) from the type Window
```

What I have to do Now?

Answer (score 2):

That is because setVisible is non static method and you are trying to refer it from static block of code/method,

In java static things gets loaded first at class load time and it will not have any knowledge of non static members so when you try to refer non static thing from static block it gives this error.

You have to call setVisible from a non static block of code that is the only solution.

Comment: Initially i was doing like that only, but now i want to use the same method for another file.. Is there any other way to call same method again and again for multiple files because i dont want to write the method for each files....

Comment: You can create an object of that class and call that method. I suggest you to refer oracle java tutorials there you will get a good learning regarding all these

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method `setVisible()` which is an instance method that means it is attached to an object instance. so, you can't invoke it without a reference to any object which has it. In order to call it, you need to make it as a static method. so, it would become a member of a class, not to any object.

You can add the `static` modifier to the method `setVisible()`. But,this can't be done since it is an inherited method from [Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) API. so, you need to make the call from a non-static context.

When you want the functionality to be across multiple classes, you can make it as an utility method and move it to a seperate class having all the utility methods

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple try this:

```
a = new login();
a.setVisible();
```

As the object created would be static it should resembles with the setVisible type. Hope i solved your doubt.

Comment: You could explain in detail how/why OP's attempt didn't work and how your answer works differently to accomplish OP's/question's intended goal.  I am a reviewer.  StackOverflow requested review due to you being a new contributor.  Your answer is much appreciated & helpful.  This comment is to help you take a good answer & make it excellent.